# How to describe R as a method in a report

Tags: r, reporting

I have to do a report, and the methods is using a given data and using R to analyse it. However, I have never wrote a report only using R.. normally when I have to write a report, the methods are based on experiments performed in laboratories. R have many formulas, do I just include the formulas I used in the methods or how do I approach it? Thanks

Comment: hello, you might need to read some R documentation and some statistical reporting guidance before doing statistical reports. However, R is not a method, it is a software that implements statistical methods.

Comment: To get the official citation for `R`, use the [?citation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/RHOME/library/utils/html/citation.html) command at the prompt in the console.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that when you use a specific piece of software in your report whether it is R or something else you provide a citation to the main piece of software in your methods section. If you use a user-written add-on package it is courteous to cite that too preferably with a reference to a publication describing it but otherwise citing a web-site. However that is not sufficient, you also need to say what you did in terms which are not software specific. So if you use a $t$-test then say so not just say which R, Stata, SAS command you used to calculate it. In R there is a citation function which generates citations for R itself and for packages, I am not sure what the preferred way of doing this is for Stata or SAS.